# How to get values when multiple conditions are true in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is my code, and what I want is that

if the key-aadhar is only present in the input, then it should call aadhar function, (or) if it has key-aadhar and some other keys-(fname,lname,dob) it should call aadhar function and preprocess function(which has keys -fname,lname,gen,dob,client-type).

same for key-pan, it should call the pan function, if only user enters pan.if user enters some details with pan, it should call pan and preprocessfunc.

If the user enters only pan and aadhar it has to call pan and aadhar functions. If he adds some keys with both of them it has to call all three functions.

```
   cust_data = {
        'fname' : data.get('firstName'),
        'lname' : data.get('lastName'),
        'gen' : data.get('gender'),
        'client_type' : data.get('cust_type'),
        'dob' : data.get('dob'),
        'aadhar': data.get('aadhar'),
        'pancard': data.get('pancard')}
```

What i have done is :

```
if aadhar is not None and pancard is not None:         #list returns
            ret.append(value)
            ret_key.append(formatting_data[key])
            try:
                prepro=preprocess_user_data(ret,ret_key)
            except TypeError:
                res_total= jsonify((aadhar_check(aadhar),pan_check(pancard)))
                # return res_total
            else:
                res_total= jsonify((prepro,aadhar_check(aadhar),pan_check(pancard)))
                return res_total
        elif aadhar!=None:
            ret.append(value)
            ret_key.append(formatting_data[key])
            try:
                prepro=preprocess_user_data(ret,ret_key)
            except TypeError:
                res_total=jsonify(aadhar_check(aadhar))
                # return res_total
            else:
                res_total= str((prepro,aadhar_check(aadhar)))#must
                # return res_total
        elif pancard!=None:#tuple ruturns
            ret.append(value)
            ret_key.append( formatting_data[key])

            try:
                prepro=preprocess_user_data(ret,ret_key)

            except TypeError:
                res_total= (pan_check(pancard))
                # return res_total
            else:
                res_total= str((prepro,pan_check(pancard)))
                # return res_total
        elif value is not None:#required good
            ret.append(value)
            ret_key.append( formatting_data[key] )#storing key value and matching with dataframe      
            res_total= (preprocess_user_data(ret,ret_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have made this thing too much complicated.

it is simple, i am mentioning logic below.

```
if aadhar!=None:
    'run aadhar function'
if pancard!=None:
    'run pan funtion'
if details != None:
    'run preprocess funtion'
```

please feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for answering but thats not i need i tried that already. What is need is if i have a dictionary with  {"firstName": "raju","lastName":"j", "gender": "female","aadhar": "543467853498"}. It has to call aadhar func and preprocess function and return both of them.If incase i have only given {"aadhar":"456789876"}, it should call only aadhar. Same with pan.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
if "aadhar" in the_dict and len(the_dict) == 1:
    # {"aadhar": 123}
elif "aadhar" in the_dict and len(the_dict) > 1:
    # {"aadhar": 123, "firstname": "ali", ...}
else:
    # {} or {"firstname": "ali", ...}
```

Comment: No, Can you please see my question. Think like this if you have a list of dicts, some keys were filled and some are not. In my condition ...nothing is mandatory. User has the right to give only one 'value'(say firstname). Like wise i have three functions specifically for ''aadhar" , "pan" and "preprocess_func(which consists of all keys). Say i have 'aadhar' key and "gender"key in dict, I have to call "aadhar function and preprocess function".Preprocess will take care of every key given, but in dict "aadhar" key is present we have to call and return that too.@GAEfan

Answer (score 0):

One can use **any** operator for checking preprocess condition.

In each if block write your function and return it.

```
 x = {
    "firstName": "raju",
    "lastName": "j",
    "gender": "female",
    "aadhar": "543467853498"
    }

keys = x.keys()
if('pan' in keys):
    print("Do the pan function and return")
if('aadhar' in keys):
    print("Do the aadhar function and return")
if any(preprocess in keys for preprocess in ["firstName", "lastName", "gender"]):
    print("Do preprocess")
```

If you have only PAN the first if will run and all will fail.

If you have PAN and Aadhar both first and second if will run.

If you have any of the three the preprocess is run.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Palakodeti Sai Vinay. Please read my comment for GAEfan Answer, Hope that will clear your doubt.

Comment: As you mentioned, It is not mandatory, I changed all to any. So if any of the one key is present. it will trigger the third if block. Based on question the logic is changed.

Comment: Does your code get the values of that keys. LIke ret.append(value) in my question

Comment: I'm sorry, your question was to get multiple conditions. You haven't mentioned what is ref or its datatype and what it does. So the answer to your question is given.